# Merging two properties for one app in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have two properties for one app in GA4. Both properties are the same but one is for before May 28th and the other is for after May 28th. Is there a way that I can merge these two properties?

I have read about using export data to BigQuery but my data is more than the limitation for one day. And actually I dont have any idea of how can I import it again from BigQuery if I decrease the volume. The import data option in GA does not have any BigQuery source option.

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics data is time sensitive.  Data is sent to the account when it happens for the most part.

There is no way to add data from a later date or to merge two accounts.